# TeeChart 2015 export to PDF unicode characters support?

Tags: delphi, vcl, teechart

How to export TeeChart with Unicode characters to PDF? 
This option seems doesn't work out of the box.
Region settings for non-Unicode applications doesn't help either.
I have tested it on TeeChart v2015, latest release.

Comment: I would very much help if we had some idea of what your code is. Since you are using the full version of TeeChart, you might request support from Steema.

Comment: Stackoverflow is mentioned as the one of the support options on the Steema website: https://steema.com/support_options.

Comment: Also there is no any specific code is required to export TeeChart to pdf, for e.g. just use TeeSaveToPDFFile method.

Comment: My understanding is that as a subscriber you have access to direct support from Steema. Have you not availed yourself of that?

Comment: This is a known issue http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=313

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what is the Stackoverflow option is given for?

Comment: I think it's for people using the lite version of TeeChart that comes bundled with Delphi. If you are a subscriber you'll get better support direct from Steema I expect.

Comment: Indeed Steema gives some priority to "Priority Support" customers by mail and to "Pro" customers through the [support forums](http://www.teechart.net/support), but we try to help people on all the [supported channels](https://www.steema.com/support_options).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to export the TeeChart content into a `TMetaFile`, then render it using our Open Source [SynPDF library](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=PDF+Engine).

The library supports Font-Fallback and Uniscribe, so has good Unicode abilities.

Comment: Why is this to be preferred to using the facilities in TeeChart? Perhaps the asker just needs to configure it properly. Or perhaps TeeChart is broken. It would be helpful if you discussed that.

Comment: In TeePDFCanvas unit source code of TeeChart 2014, the font description is just hard coded with flags "/Subtype /TypeScript" and "/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding", which, as i understand, will support limited amount of characters by default. I can assume that nothing much changed in 2015 implementation.